# Check if certain bits are set in a DWORD

Tags: c++

My question: I'm looking at the Characteristics member of the `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` struct. I want to know if a certain section is executable or not. How would I go about checking this? The Characteristics member is a `DWORD`, and I want to be able to know if it contains the value `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE` (`0x20000000`). What would the calculation for this look like? I'm guessing I have to use the modulo operator, but have no idea how.

Comment: I took a liberty of refining the title to be of more use to future generations.

Comment: `bitfield` has a specific meaning in C and C++ (and this question doesn't refer to it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (imageSectionHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE)
{
   // Do work here...
}
```

This is called masking. You're masking the `Characteristics` value with `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE` mask to see if those specific bits are set. The condition above will only be true if all the bits set in the `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE` mask are also set in the `Characteristics` value.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't even know about the & operator. I have to wait 10 more minutes to mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: @user2073973: I'm sure there are lots of more good stuff C++ has to offer you as you continue using it. Reading a good book on C++ language would not hurt, I suppose :)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I dont think bitwise AND is c++ only ;)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER::Characteristics` is a bit field. You want to check if the bit denoted by `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE` is set. To do that, you do the bitwise AND between `Characteristics` and `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE`:

```
header.Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE
```

When converted to `bool`, this expression will be `true` only if the `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE` bit is set.

Comment: @user2073973 The result of a bitwise AND will have bits set only where both operands have bits set. For example, `0011 & 0101` will give you `0001` because only the last bit is set in both. Now each bit in `Characteristics` represents a particular characteristic. To filter out a particular bit, you can bitwise AND it with a value containing only that bit. For example, if I want to check if the 3rd bit (from the right) is set in `0101`, I can do `0101 & 0100`. This would give me `0100` back. Since this is greater than 0, it will become `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Found some facts about windows flag design :

Lets assume Flag A is "0x0001000", B is "0x0002000" and C is "0x0003000".

Characteristics may contain multibyte flag. Suppose exe contains flag A & B. 
Then Characteristics value will be "0x0003000".

if we are checking (Characteristics&(A|B)) this will be okay but (Characteristics&(C)) will also return true.

But Microsoft designed flags in such way that no multiple flags having possibility to come together and form third flag.
If we check possible values of Characteristics closly, there are some intermediate values which are skipped to avoid above issue.

Bitwise AND(&) will always work for flag checking.

For Safety one can also write expression as follows:
if we wants to check for Flag1 & Flag2 in Characteristics.

((Characteristics & (Flag1|Flag2|Highest Bit flag in flag list)==(Flag1|Flag2))